# update server IP from menu bar

Tags: java, android

for some reason I cannot update my server ID from my client app. I'm using the menu tab (3 dots) do pull up a screen so you can update the IP but it's not updating. I think I just need the string from the IP update to run through the connection again

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setServerIP();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

private void setServerIP() {
    serverIP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("SERVER_IP", "192.168.21.16");

    try {
        serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP); 
        getActionBar().setSubtitle("Broadcasting touch events to "+serverIP+":4444");
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId() ){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent n = new Intent(this,Prefs.class);
            startActivityForResult(n, 0);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    setServerIP();

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            connected = true;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidating the menu in `setServerIp()` with [invalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) so that the action bar knows it needs to be redrawn.